# es posible agregar una función en el evento de filtrar los datos de un datatable?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

Lo que quiero es que cada vez que se ingrese una letra en el input de búsqueda, también se ejecute una función propia...

Comment: ¿Puedes poner lo que has intentado o el código de tu aplicación?

Comment: Hola, es posible, puedes ponerle a tu input el atributo `onchange="funcion()"`y en la función lo que necesitas, pero mejora la pregunta y agrega el código donde quieres que corra.

Comment: @Kiko_L es que es en la opción de buscar que se genera automáticamente al utilizar datatable por lo cual yo no he creado el input, lo genera datatable y quiero que al utilizar ese filtro de busqueda tambien ejecute una funcion propia...

Comment: Hola @csjo, sería ideal que crearas un [mcve] (por básico que sea) para poder ver el problema y lo que has intentado para resolverlo. Además, ¿quieres que se ejecute una función propia cada vez que se ingrese una letra o con el evento de filtrar datos? (que puede no ser lo mismo)

Comment: @csjo Estas utilizando algún plugin para el datatable, en aso de ser así, ¿cual es? y sin importar creo que tu puedes modificar el código para que tenga una función personalizada, pero si es importante saber que utilizas para generar el datatable

Comment: @JulioMorenoDev la etiqueta [tag:datatables] indica que es el plugin de jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quieres usar el [controlador del evento `search`](https://datatables.net/reference/event/search) dentro de la DataTable (traducción mía):

> El evento `search` se dispara cuando la búsqueda de la tabla es lanzada por las opciones de búsqueda global o por columnas, incluyendo llamadas desde la API (`search()` por ejemplo). Además, un redibujado completo (al llamar a `draw()`) también causará que la tabla sea re-buscada.
>
> Nota que la búsqueda se disparará antes de que la tabla sea redibujada con los datos filtrados y actualizados, aunque los datos ya se habrán filtrado internamente.

Entonces lo que tendrías que hacer sería algo como esto:

```
var tabla = $('#miTabla').DataTable();

tabla.on('search.dt', function() {
  // código a ejecutar cuando se filtra
});
```

Comment: funciona perfectamente asi... gracias por tu ayuda  @Alvaro Montoro